# How to populate a char array with alphabet?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a question about char array. How do I declare an array of char from `a` to `z` in Java?

I mean something like:

```
char  characters []=new char[]{a....z]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char[] alphabet = new char[26];
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
    alphabet[c - 'a'] = c;
}
```

Comment: is there any other way of doing it sev??
like how we do /a-z/ in regular expression  ?!

Answer (score 0):

Declare an empty array, and fill it manually with a loop.